# Generate Screenshots From APK ( Online )

Tags: php, android, node.js

Is there any way to Generate Screenshots From APK online by only upload the APK with no need to install it on a phone and take one by one screenshot?

Steps to explain the idea:

1 - Enter the website or open the app

2 - Find the APK file then upload it

3 - I get 5-10 screenshots from the app

Answer (score 1):

By definition, this is impossible. The UI is generated by Java code. Only by executing that Java code, along with the associated resources, will a screen be generated that you can capture. That requires installing the Android app into an Android environment, running the app, and then doing something to manipulate the app (otherwise, your 5-10 screenshots will mostly be the same, since the UI will be sitting waiting for user input).

You could use an emulator, rather than hardware, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `diawi.com`.
Diawi is a tool for developers to deploy development and in-house applications directly to the devices.